# How to get the value from JSON

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2015

I have the API like below.

```
[
 {
  "name":"test1",
  "commit":{
     "id":"8595fad8cd84c7a630c5d7a78414f9c",
     "short_id":"8595fad8",
     "title":"title 1",
     "created_at":"2017-05-29T07:18:36.000+00:00",
     "parent_ids":[
        "74956b0bcd370f3ddc75d7db00336099cce20501"
     ],
     "message":"Update README.md",
     "author_name":"Administrator",
     "author_email":"email.com",
     "authored_date":"2017-05-29T07:18:36.000+00:00",
     "committer_name":"Administrator",
     "committer_email":"email.com",
     "committed_date":"2017-05-29T07:18:36.000+00:00"
  },
  "merged":true,
  "protected":false,
  "developers_can_push":false,
  "developers_can_merge":false
 },
......
]
```

My class is

```
protected class BranchData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Merged { get; set; }
    public string Protected { get; set; }
    public string Authored_Date { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to get all the above valve. But I did not get the value for `authored_date`.

My code is

```
var jSONString = reader.ReadToEnd();
branchDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BranchData>>(jSONString);
```

I get all the class value in `branchDetails` list except `authored_date`(null).

How could I get rid from this?

Comment: `Authored_Date` comes from an inner object. Create a new class with that as its only property, then add that as a property of `BranchData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @willaien already mentioned, you should create dedicated `Commit` object, in order to get `Authored_Data` information.

```
protected class BranchData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Merged { get; set; }
    public string Protected { get; set; }
    public CommitData Commit { get; set; }
}

protected class CommitData
{ 
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "authored_date")]
    public string AuthoredDate { get; set; }
    //...other Commit object properties
}
```

Comment: Just as a note, the "other Commit object properties" are optional.  If you don't include them they will be ignored but not cause any errors for your program.

Answer (score 0):

Authored_Date is a property of "commit".
Create a Commit class, and put Authored_Date as it's property.
Then in BranchData, add a Commit property.